# Set format "dd-mm-yyyy" of an input type="date" html

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, format

Good morning everyone.
I have a little problem formatting a date.

I would like to make sure, with Javascript, that today's date is shown by default in an html `<input type="date>"` in this format: `"dd-mm-yyyy"`.
I managed to do this by changing the input to `<input type="text">`, the problem is that this way the automatic date picker that exists when the input is `<input type="date">`  no longer works.

So I would like to keep the `<input type="date">` to keep the default datepicker, but show the default date same as today's, in this `"dd-mm-yyyy"` format.

How can I do?
Thanks a lot to everyone.
Forgive my bad English.

I tried with this portion of code:
`let today= new Date();`
`let day = oggi.getDate();`
`let month = oggi.getMonth() + 1;`
`let year = oggi.getFullYear();`

`if(day < 10) giorno = '0' + giorno;`
`if(month < 10) mese = '0' + mese;`

`let formattedDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;`

`document.getElementById('DATE').value = formattedDate;`

now this code function only if the input type in html is `<input type="text">`, unfortunately in this way, the datepicker present when input `<input type="date">` is not displayed.

If i change the html `<input type="date">`, the default today date doesn't be shown on the input that remains empty.

Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+set+date+format+on+input) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Please may you share a [mcve] of the issue besides the description? It's good what you've got, but you seem to be missing details a working example would show